What is the generated html element for ag-grid tool tip?
Is it possible to get the ag-grid tool tip html elements / values from the DOM?
I'm successfully using cypress to select (from the web page) the rows and cells html elements generated by ag-grid (we're using ag-grid in an angular app / component).  However, we have tool tips for many of our ag-grid column cells, and I can't find a way to select them.  I created a small ag-grid test, went into Chrome Browser DevTools and copied the generated html.  I see ag-grid's generated column headings, rows, columns, etc. but I don't see the tool tip.  I created a tool tip for the rowData field, 'make', using the rowData 'price' field (to be able to more easily search for the tooltip values in the generated html).
Following is menu.component.ts (angular component that uses ag-grid):
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AgGridAngular } from 'ag-grid-angular';

import {
  ColDef,
  ColGroupDef,
  GridApi,
  GridOptions,
  ITooltipParams,
  ModuleRegistry,
  createGrid,
} from "ag-grid-community";

import { IVehicle } from './IVehicle';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AgGridAngular],
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrl: './menu.component.css'
})
export class MenuComponent {

    columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
        { field: "make", tooltipField: "price" },
        { field: "model" }
    ];

    rowData: IVehicle[] = [
        { make: "Tesla", model: "Model Y", price: 64950, electric: true },
        { make: "Ford", model: "F-Series", price: 33850, electric: false },
        { make: "Toyota", model: "Corolla", price: 29600, electric: false },
    ];
    
    gridOptions: GridOptions<IVehicle> = {
        defaultColDef: {
            flex: 1,
            minWidth: 100,
        },
        rowData: null, 
        columnDefs: this.columnDefs,
        tooltipShowDelay: 500,
    };
    
    ngOnInit(){ 
        let gridDiv = document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("#myGrid")!;
        let gridApi: GridApi<IVehicle> = createGrid(gridDiv, this.gridOptions);
        gridApi!.setGridOption("rowData", this.rowData);
    }
}

menu-component.html:
<div id="myGrid" class="ag-theme-quartz" style="height: 500px">
</div>

IVehicle.ts:
export interface IVehicle {
    make: string;
    model: string;
    price: number;
    electric: boolean;
}


Isn't the tooltip just a modal/absolute-positioned DIV that is inserted somewhere at the bottom of the DOM? I think it has the class ag-tooltip.

@Mr.Polywhirl  I looked at the generated html via Chrome’s DevTools and saw all the expected ag-grid-generated html elements (the rows, columns, etc) but not the tool tips.  I copy/pasted the html into a text file and searched for the tool tip values, for “tool”, “tip”, and examined pretty much all the html elements & I don’t see it.

The tooltip element might only be present in the DOM while actively displayed.

ag-grid is storing the tool tip data in the ColDef object I give it so ... I'm thinking if I were to potentially deep-dive the ag-grid code I could look to invoke its code (JS) for returning the tool tip value.  Also thinking that if I were to programmatically via cypress do a mouse over (if possible) that I could then potentially get the rendered tool tip html.  Thinking out loud ...
